# Why cannot I JSON.stringify localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, stringify

I tried this one

```
JSON.stringify(localStorage, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key);
        return (key.split('.')[0] === 'SUWDdb') ? value : undefined;
})
```

and it only returns undefined, console only log one entries.
can any one give me a reason and a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing at the top level satisfies your condition, and in that case your function is returning undefined, which means nothing below that is stringified. You probably want:

```
JSON.stringify(localStorage, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    return (typeof value === 'object' || key.split('.')[0] === 'SUWDdb') ? value : undefined;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

This will allow `JSON.stringify` to keep traversing downward when it encounters an object.

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I use your approach and it works!!! You have just saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple if you have localstorage and you want to stringify it use

JSON.stringify(localstorage)
Where localstorage is variable that has localstorage object

jsonString = JSON.stringify(value [, replacer [, space]])

value The JavaScript object to convert into a JSON string.

replacer A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for selecting the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.

This is the syntax of json.stringify function,its not a callback function

Comment: What does this mean for his use case where he wants to omit properties whose keys start with `SUWDdb.`?

Comment: Var result= JSON.stringify(localstorage)